# Is it illegal to hang lingerie on a clothesline near an airport in Kidderville, NH?

Tags: united-states, law

There are some [online sources](https://twitter.com/jetcitystar/status/422595354102489088) claiming that, in Kidderville NH (USA), it is illegal to hang lingerie on the clothesline if you live near an airport.

Is this true?

Comment: Can you find any other sources?

Comment: Here's one: http://www.mydailymoment.com/love/all_love_tips/strangest_sex_laws_in_the_u.s.php

Comment: The source is the magazine "Private Pilot" November 1987.  It only says "at" the airport however.  See page 7 here https://www.mdt.mt.gov/publications/docs/newsletters/aeronautics/2004/aeromar04.pdf